# How to specify array elements as property values in an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Lets say I have an array

```
var array = ["lionel", "messi"];
```

I want to use the values of the elements of that array for property values in an object.

```
var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
}
```

I want the final object to be,

```
var obj = {
  "first-name": "lionel",
  "last-name": "messi"
}
```

How do I do this in JavaScript? Or is there a lodash function which can do this?

Comment: Is there any structure to the array? Can we assume anything about the length of the array and the structure of the object, the variables, etc?

Comment: Is it really an array of objects your are looking for here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Did it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just assign to those properties:

```
obj["first-name"] = array[0];
obj["last-name"] = array[1];
```

Example:

```js
var array = ["lionel", "messi"];
var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
};
obj["first-name"] = array[0];
obj["last-name"] = array[1];
console.log(obj);
```

In ES2015+, you can use a destructuring assignment:

```
[obj["first-name"], obj["last-name"]] = array;
```

Example:

```js
var array = ["lionel", "messi"];
var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
};
[obj["first-name"], obj["last-name"]] = array;
console.log(obj);
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> but what if I had to do it dynamically? How do I loop over both in the array/object?

***If*** you mean that you want to assign the entries from `array` to the object properties in `obj` by their *position*, **beware that object property order is new as of ES2015** and it's easily misunderstood.

But with a fully ES2015+ compliant JavaScript engine, **if** your object really is defined as:

```
var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
};
```

...then `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will reliably return `["first-name", "last-name"]` (`Object.keys` is **not** guaranteed to), because:

1. The properties were created in that order by the object initializer
2. They're "own" properties
3. They have string names (not Symbol names),
4. They don't look like array indexes, and
5. It's an ordinary object

Yes, that's quite a lot of caveats. So you could use that, like this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    obj[key] = array[index];
});
```

Example:

```js
var array = ["lionel", "messi"];
var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    obj[key] = array[index];
});
console.log(obj);
```

**Again:** That only works on a fully ES2015+ compliant JavaScript engine, with an object defined as shown above. The order in which properties are reported by `getOwnPropertyNames` is potentially complex; [details in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys).

Comment: but what if I had to do it dynamically? How do I loop over both in the array/object?

Comment: @SaiCharan: Loop over what? You have only one entry in what you've shown. An array defining data for Lionel Messi, and an object with room to hold **one** person's data. If you have multiple of these, you need to show us that. For one thing, the structure of your object will be quite different.

Comment: @SaiCharan: If you mean that `array[0]` should be assigned to the "first" property of `obj`, I've added to the answer to explain how to do that on 
a fully ES2015+ compliant JavaScript engine. You **cannot** reliably do it on a pre-ES2015 engine.

Comment: thank you so much! `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach((key, index) => {
    obj[key] = array[index];
});`

this is the answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: @SaiCharan: No worries! Just do take note of the caveats, that won't work on IE11 and earlier for instance (and there's no other *reliable* way, cross-browser; you'd have to make your own array of property names).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```js
var array = ["lionel", "messi"];
var order = ["first-name", "last-name"];

var obj = {
  "first-name": "cristiano",
  "last-name": "ronaldo"
}

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  obj[order[i]] = array[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Every thing is pretty self-explanatory, except for the `Object.keys(obj)` part. It just returns an array of the keys of obj(`["first-name", "last-name"]) it gets each one and assigns them to you array.

EDIT:

Also, as tibetty said in the comment, you need an order array.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that the language spec itself doesn't guarantee that the fields of an object is ordered as we declare, although most nowadays implementations do.

Comment: @tibetty: It would **if** the author had used `getOwnPropertyNames`. But `Object.keys` does indeed not have that guarantee (because it predates ES2015, when order was defined).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement as:

```
function heteroCopy(obj, array) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (let i in keys) {
        obj[keys[i]] = array[i];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: The problem of this solution is that the language spec itself doesn't guarantee that the fields of an object is ordered as we declare, although most nowadays implementations do.

Comment: It would **if** you had used `getOwnPropertyNames`. But `Object.keys` does indeed not have that guarantee (because it predates ES2015, when order was defined).

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has no concept of associative array like PHP. You can create JSON (Javascript Object Notation). And please try to understand the concept of using object. Don't use object because you want to use it like array. Javascript has the concept of classes. You can create class having member first name , last name. Instance it and assign your values.